# Http Json Post Response js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, httprequest

I have written a demo app at eclipse and I have a MySQL database.

I'm using hibernate to retrieve data from the database and now I want to 
show up them to a browser.

I have a `UserLogin` class which is a `servlet`; the class waits for a `HttpRequest` and then the hibernate is being enable to bring me back the result set of the database.

By far, it works well; I have check my server side component using Postman and I do get a response as expected from my class, `UserLogin`.

My challenge is that I'm not really familiar with front-end.

I have the example below, using JavaScript with HTML in order to make a HTTP request.

I have check from my chrome browser's console and got the response below:

```
{"response":"ok","FileSystem":"Internal","userID":1}
```

but I need to be able to manipulate it (the response above) so as to display it on the page.

How can I achieve that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UserLogin</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><input id="username" type="text"     name="username" placeholder="username"></p>
<p><input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"></p>

<button onclick="return login()">Submit</button>

<script>
    function login() {
       
        const params = {
            username: document.querySelector('#username').value,
            password: document.querySelector('#password').value
        }

        const http = new XMLHttpRequest()
        http.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/.../UserLogin', true)
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;')
        http.send(JSON.stringify(params)) // Make sure to stringify

        http.onload = function() {

            console.log(http.responseText)

        }
    }
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you want to add some elements to the `<body>` based on the response?

Comment: yeah , sounds good

Comment: Seems like you need to read up on [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), and possibly [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)